# Strain relief for cable into metal box - clamp ok?

Tags: metal, nec, rough-in

I am having trouble fining a strain relief clamp to cover the hole into a metal canister (the canister for a heating unit). Is it ok to use an NM cable clamp - the kind you use around the hole going into a metal junction box (where you tighten the clamp by turning the 2 screws)? Is this considered a strain relief by the "average" inspector?

Comment: If I understand correctly a normal feed with NM cable it would be code compliant to the junction box. There are also snap in plastic ones but I use the metal.... Guess this is old school but the plastic protect and hold the cable just fine.

Comment: The metal canister has a standard 1/2" conduit KO on it I take it?

Comment: Yes, it has a 1/2" knockout. We couldn't find the plastic ones big enough to take 12 gauge, so I'll use the cable clamps and cross my fingers. Thanks.

Comment: This is a NM cable you're feeding into the canister, correct, and not some flexible cord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your can has a standard 1/2" knockout, this is what the NM clamps are designed for -- it's simply an odd-shaped box from the Code's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use strain reliefs/clamps which are correct (i.e. listed) for the cable you are using.   For instance if you have cordage (cable designed to be a flexible appliance power cord), don't use a strain relief intended for NM *simply because it's the only thing Home Depot sells*.

Home improvement shops like Home Depot or Lowes have **notoriously bad selection** in this sort of "oddball stuff"; they do not want to stock it because their business is all about volume.  A proper electrical supply house will have the right strain reliefs; bring them a cable sample and they'll put you right.

As an aside, you need to use flexible cable that's correct for the usage (assuming flexible cable is allowed at all).  The most common mistake is using NM cable for cordage.  Again, the electrical supply will have a variety and can also advise you.